# How to add my network library integration into FBReaderj in android?

Tags: android

I am new in the field of ANdroid.

I am using FBReaderj code for my project.

I want to download a book from my website.

In FBREADERJ they have integrated with three site.

I want to add my own.

Any ideas ??

Please Help..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

1. download Android NDK, 
   from: http://developer.mips.com/android/download-android-ndk/
2. put ndk in the folder which is containing your project.
3. Go to eclipse, select build path and select source.
4. Select Add folder
5. select your project and gen folder.
6. click ok and again click ok.
7. Run your project

Answer (score 0):

Try to figure out the code (good luck, it's a mess!), write a patch and send them.